# Linkedin signin: Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have the following button in http://localhost/index.php:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&state=adasd8asd8sad&scope=r_basicprofile&redirect_uri=http://localhost/linkedin.php">Linked in</a>
```

Then at the redirect_url I have the following php code:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'client_id'     => '123456789',
    'client_secret' => 'abcdefghijklm',
    'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    'code'          => $_REQUEST['code'],
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/index.php',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);die;
```

However this results in this:

> string(263) "{"error_description":"missing required parameters,
>   includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. :
>   Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match
>   authorization code or authorization code
>   expired","error":"invalid_request"}"

I would also like to say that after the link is clicked, its maximum 2 seconds untill the code in linkedin.php is run. So its well within the 20seconds linkedin requires. so it really cant be expired.

**Developer Console in Linkedin:**

redirect urls configured are:
http://localhost/linkedin.php and
http://localhost/index.php

'client_id'     => '123456789' (obscured),
'client_secret' => 'abcdefghijklm' (obscured)

Default Application Permissions: r_basicprofile

Can anyone see why I get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `/accessToken` endpoint, you must specify the same `redirect_uri` value as you did for the initial `/authorization` request. See the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3). Now your values differ:

- `http://localhost/linkedin.php`
- `http://localhost/index.php`